# How do I add several library path in ansible.cfg file

Tags: python, ansible, library-path

I've installed napalm-ansible using pip, and now trying to add napalm-ansible library path into my ansible.cfg file.

```
root@usvr-1804:/home/labadmin# napalm-ansible
To ensure Ansible can use the NAPALM modules you will have
to add the following configurtion to your Ansible configuration
file (ansible.cfg):

[defaults]
library = /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/napalm_ansible/modules
action_plugins = /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist 
packages/napalm_ansible/plugins/action
```

But my ansible.cfg file already has a library path.

```
root@usvr-1804:/home/labadmin# cat ansible.cfg

[defaults]
inventory = ./hosts
library = /etc/ansible/roles/PaloAltoNetworks.paloaltonetworks
host_key_checking = false
timeout = 5
log_path = /var/log/ansible.log
roles_path = /etc/ansible/roles
```

How do I add a second library path to my ansible.cfg file. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Go to [the docs for the Ansible Configuration Settings](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#ansible-configuration-settings)
, find the right parameter [`library`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#default-module-path):

> `library` Colon separated paths in which Ansible will search for Modules.

then configure accordingly:

```
library = /etc/ansible/roles/PaloAltoNetworks.paloaltonetworks:/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/napalm_ansible/modules
```

Comment: Thanks you all for the answer

Answer (score 2):

You can put as many paths as you want to the `library` parameter into the section `[defaults]`, you need just to put a colon between each path ([documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.4/intro_configuration.html#library))

```
[defaults]
...
library = /foo/bar:/foo/baz
```